# How can I add qty for custom option before adding product to cart

Tags: magento

I want to create a functionality to add qty for each individual custom option. For example I have to create a basket and there I want to add 2 apple, 3 quinces, 1 melon.

After the help of **Ashlesha** I've manage to have something very good. Right now I have another problem that pops out from this one. I've done the change on Check box because I want to configure the product with check boxes and add quantity on every one.

Question: How can I auto update the price and quantity after I do this? (on product page and then pass it to checkout)

```
<span class="label">
    <label for="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getSelectionQtyTitlePrice($_selection) ?> 
    </label>

    <input <?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo '' ?> id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input" class="input-text qty<?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo '' ?>" type="text" name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_defaultQty ?>" onclick="bundle.changeSelection(this)"/></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating bundled products. While creating bundle items create radio selection and select only one option for that particular radio selection.

> For example you can create products named apple ,quinces and melon.
>   Then create a bundled product basket and go to Bundle items.

```
 Add new options->Select radio button and No for required option->Click Add
 Selection->Select Apple(only one product)->then Click Add selected
 product to options.
```

> Also remember to keep Quantity option user defined.
>   Similarly do this for other Quinces and melon.

Later go to

> /magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml

and alter this line

```
 <label for="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>&nbsp;</label><input <?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?> id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input" class="input-text qty<?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' qty-disabled' ?>" type="text" name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_defaultQty ?>"/>
```

to

```
 <label for="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>&nbsp;</label><input <?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo '' ?> id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input" class="input-text qty<?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo '' ?>" type="text" name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_defaultQty ?>"/>
```

As it does not allow to alter quantity if there are more then one radio options for one bundled product.
This way you can also maintain your quantity for all product being added.
Also you can alter the radio.phtml file as you want for labeling purpose.
Hope this will help you.

**EDITED:**

Try this extension `http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/kabel-bundleplus.html`. I think this will do your work.

Comment: Thank you for this. It helps a lot but now I have another problem. Can you please help me on this one also? I've edited the post with what I have.

Comment: Hey andy1786, check the above extension

Comment: If you want can you help me with some other problems related with Magento? Can you please give me your email address?